# What is the specific use case of the 'direction' style?

Tags: html, css

So while browsing some blogs and forums I came across this line of code.

```
body{
direction: rtl;
}
```

and

```
body{
direction: ltr;
}
```

I ended up trying it in inspect element and I see that it swaps the side the text is aligned, but some things like "!" in my titles were placed before. Is there and actual use case for this element, or was there and it's now depreciated?

**[Here is an example of it in use](https://jsfiddle.net/zLgudvf5/)**. I originally thought it was maybe for accessibility but it seems to butcher a lot of the text, has anyone used this or is it a dead style?

Comment: "has anyone used this or is it a dead style".  A dead style? There **are** right to left languages: Persian, Arabic, Hebrew, etc.

Comment: @Vohuman I said it was maybe for accessibility, but it does butcher a lot of the punctuation.

Comment: this is to apply css on particular direction...rtl means right to left and ltr means left to right

Comment: If you speak Hebrew or Arabic for example, you wouldn't consider RTL direction as a "dead style"

Comment: Related: https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-dir

Comment: @AlonEitan I don't speak either of those so I don't know/understand how the language would be written. That being said, I've always figured there would be something in place when a page gets translated.

Comment: `אבגדהוזחטיכלמנסעפצקרשת` - Here's the hebrew alphabet (Should be read from right to left **:)**)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the direction style is primarily used in web-development where the end-user's language is written/read from a different direction. It is especially useful for websites that have multi-lingual options as it can fix the placement of your punctuation etc.

There is a lovely explanation on css-tricks that goes in to more detail:
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/direction/

Hope this helps!

Comment: I searched around and didn't find anything useful originally, this is a great link. thanks!